# System.Comparison<T> understanding

Tags: .net

`List<T>.Sort()` method has 3 overloads.

One of them is the following

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T>.Sort(System.Comparison<T>)
```

On seeing `Comparison<T>`, I thought that it should be a class which is derived from `Comparison<T>` class. (An usual interpretation on the parameters)

But the following works really well and said to be using the above overload.

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Int32> collection = new List<Int32>();

            collection.Add(20);
            collection.Add(270);
            collection.Add(30);
            collection.Add(90);
            collection.Add(40);
            collection.Add(18);
            collection.Add(100);

            collection.Sort(MyComparer.CompareWithCase);

            foreach (Int32 s in collection)
                Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        public static int CompareWithCase(int i1, int i2)
        {
            return i1.ToString().CompareTo(i2.ToString());
        }
```

I did give a delegate to a static Method in place of `Comparison<T>`.
How does it work?

Comment: Please don't tag your questions ".net2.0" unless they are specific to .NET 2.0.

Comment: I don't understand why John Saunders wouldn't wnat this to be tagged .NET 2.0, since this question is not applicable to .NET 1.1 or earlier.  And how often does someone have a question that only applies to 1 version of .NET.  Usually a question applies to a version and all newer versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`System.Comparison<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) is defined as follows:

```
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(T x, T y);
```

That means that it's [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(VS.80).aspx), not a class. A method accepting a delegate as a parameter actually accepts a method, not an instance of a Comparison class.

This code can be rewritten as follows with a lambda expression:

```
collection.Sort((i1, i2) => i1.ToString().CompareTo(i2.ToString()));
```

The following snippet might explain better what happens:

```
public static class TestClass {

  public static void Main(string[] args){
      Comparison<Int32> comparisonDelegate = CompareWithCase;
      //We now can use comparisonDelegate as though it is a method;
      int result = comparisonDelegate(1,2);
  }

  public static int CompareWithCase(int i1, int i2)
  {
     return i1.ToString().CompareTo(i2.ToString());
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`System.Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) *is* a delegate.

```
public delegate int Comparison<in T>(
    T x,
    T y
)
```

The signature of your `CompareWithCase` method makes it perfectly assignable to `Comparison<int>`.

Note that without type-inferencing, your `Sort` call would have had to be written as:

```
 collection.Sort(new Comparison<int>(MyComparer.CompareWithCase));
```

FYI, The other 2 overloads of `List<T>.Sort` expect `IComparer<T>` implementations